# Errors sending through Mailgun: '421 Syntax error'

Tags: mailgun

I am sending emails through a node.js app to Mailgun. I keep getting these 421 Syntax error messages come up. Sometimes the messages do end up going through, here is the history for one message:

```
Date/Time   Summary 
2015-05-07 16:14    Delivered: sender → recipient 'You have a new notification' 
2015-05-07 15:14    Will retry in 3600 seconds: sender → recipient 'You have a new notification' Server response: 421 421 Syntax error  
2015-05-07 14:43    Will retry in 1800 seconds: sender → recipient  'You have a new notification' Server response: 421 421 Syntax error 
2015-05-07 14:28    Will retry in 900 seconds: sender → recipient  'You have a new notification' Server response: 421 421 Syntax error  
2015-05-07 14:18    Will retry in 600 seconds: sender → recipient  'You have a new notification' Server response: 421 421 Syntax error  
2015-05-07 14:18    Accepted: sender → recipient  'You have a new notification'
```

*Email addresses redacted.

Here is what the log says for the 421 error:

```
{
  "severity": "temporary",
  "tags": [],
  "delivery-status": {
    "retry-seconds": 600,
    "message": "421 Syntax error",
    "code": 421,
    "description": null,
    "session-seconds": 0.16810393333435059
  },
  "envelope": {
    "transport": "smtp",
    "sender": sender,
    "sending-ip": "184.173.153.222",
    "targets": recipient
  },
  "recipient-domain": domain,
  "id": "TdCQ8omOSwqj_zYq18CBdQ",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "generic",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "log-level": "warn",
  "timestamp": 1431029901.450764,
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": recipient,
      "message-id": "20150507201819.16176.81911@mailgundomain",
      "from": sender,
      "subject": "You have a new notification"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      recipient
    ],
    "size": 1036
  },
  "recipient": recipient,
  "event": "failed"
}
```

I am new to using Mailgun and I am building the emails RAW (headers and all). A 421 is supposed to be for network errors... so 'Syntax error' doesn't make sense to me.

Some of the messages go through fine, but I do have an awful lot that are getting retried.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the MX records setup for Mailgun? Sometimes 421 status indicate an email provider blocking your server because it's not trusted

Comment: I do have two MX records setup. I just checked mailgun's domain verification and one of the MX was unverified and then I checked it again and it verified. So it's all green now. Maybe that's what the issue was? I'll have to wait until tomorrow to see if the retries start going through.

Comment: Yea I think you won't be seeing them anymore. Similar thing happened to me until the MX records propagated.

Comment: Every now and then the emails seem to go through, but I'm still getting this 421 Syntax Error most of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a ticket with Mailgun support and they quickly helped me find the answer:

```
The error that you are seeing is due to the recipient's server either 
1). throttling emails sent from your domain which is also known as ESP
throttling, 2) grey-listing of the IP in which the recipient server will
first verify that the sending server is not sending spam before allowing
delivery, or 3) a local server issue may have occurred such as the server
being offline or misconfigured.

The error code of "4xx" indicates that this is a soft, temporary bounce.
Whenever we attempt to deliver a message and the recipient server returns a
soft bounce, we will retry delivery for up to 8 hours in the following
intervals: 10 minutes, 10 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hour
and 4 hours. Unfortunately this cannot be adjusted and is hard coded in our
environment.
```

I checked with our admin and we had some anti-spam turned on for the mail server. We turned it off and no longer get '421 Syntax Errors'.

Thanks